# How to have a solid color desktop background with AERO theme enabled on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, aero, desktop-customization

I need the Aero theme enabled on my Windows 7 machine because a program I use requires it (Sticky Previews).

However, I want a solid color as my desktop background.

(I want this because I am accessing the Windows 7 machine (on which I want to enable Aero with a solid desktop background color) remotely using Teamviewer and my local machine has a video playing as the desktop background using Deskscapes and inactive windows are transparent using WindowFX, so the desktop background of the remote Windows 7 machine interferes with the local desktop background when the remote window is inactive.)

I simply cannot find a way to enable the Aero theme on my remote Windows 7 machine, while at the same time setting the desktop background to a solid color.  Every time I switch the desktop background to a solid color, Aero is automatically disabled.

Surely it must be possible to have an Aero theme that displays just a solid color as the desktop background in Windows 7 on this remote machine.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: @Ramhound I meant Windows 7, not Windows 10.  I just spaced out when I wrote the question.  I've just edited the question.

Comment: @Ramhound The remote machine is Windows 7.  The local machine is Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound I have carefully read through the question and added clarifying parenthetical comments.  Thanks!

Comment: 3 years and still no answer!?